# Javascript - Can't get my program to run - Loop never ends

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement, parameter-passing, case

My program is not running correctly.  It should prompt you for your name and store it - then asks you to choose option 1,2 or 3(exit and return to choice) - do-while loop.  My functions then aren't being called e.g. If user types 1 then Opt1 is called, user types 2 Opt2 is called.  Totally lost if anyone can help that would be amazing.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        var me;
        function Menu () {
            var choice;
            me = prompt("Who are you?"," ") ;

            do {
                prompt("Choose option 1, 2 or 3" + choice);
                choice = parseInt(choice);

                switch (choice) {
                    case 1: {
                        Opt1();
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2: {
                        Opt2();
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3: {
                        alert("All done");
                        break;
                    }
                } //end of switch
            } //end of do-while

            while (choice != 3); {
                break;
            }

        } //end Menu

        function Opt1()
        {
            var user;
            alert(me + "This is Option 1") ;
            user = prompt("Enter first and last name");
            alert('Welcome ' + create_name(user));
            create_name(user);
        }

        function Opt2()
        {
            alert(me + 'This is Option 2' + me);
        }

        function create_name(username) { //string manipulation
            var string1 = username.substr(0,1);
            alert("Hello" + string1);
            var len = username.length;
            alert("the number of letters in your name is " + len);
            var pos = username.indexOf(" ");

            alert("the space is located at position " + pos);
            var string2 = username.substr(pos+1);
            username = string1+string2;

            alert ('Welcome ' + username);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Software Program</h1>
    <input type="button" value="Menu" onclick="Menu();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should learn to indent your code first... it's pretty unreadable.

Comment: `while (choice != 3); { break;}` should be `while (choice != 3);`

Answer (score 0):

@CodeiSir is right, but the real problem is that you're not collecting the value entered by the user.

Change this

```
                prompt("Choose option 1, 2 or 3" + choice);
```

with this:

```
                choice = prompt("Choose option 1, 2 or 3");
```

Regards